# Multiple image in parse relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

i'm trying to create relationship between multiple images to an object. I keep getting following error:

## errorcode

```
All objects in a relation must have object ids
```

What am i doing wrong? i've tried to follow documentation and adjust it to my example.

## relationship code.

```
    homeObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Homes"];
    homeObject[@"userId"] = [PFUser currentUser].objectId;       
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.assets count]; i++) {                        
        PFObject *object = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"homeImages"];
        ALAsset *asset = [self.assets objectAtIndex:i];
        ALAssetRepresentation *representation = asset.defaultRepresentation;            
        UIImage *fullResolutionImage =
        [UIImage imageWithCGImage:representation.fullResolutionImage
                            scale:1.0f
                      orientation:(UIImageOrientation)representation.orientation];            
        NSData *imgData= UIImageJPEGRepresentation(fullResolutionImage,0.0);
        PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Image.jpg" data:imgData];
        object[@"Image"] = imageFile;
        [object saveInBackground];
        PFRelation *relation = [homeObject relationforKey:@"imageId"];
        [relation addObject:object];                                   
    }
    [homeObject saveInBackground];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the file and wait for it to finish saving (in the background), then you can safely attach it to your `homeImages` object. Next you need to save that object and wait for it to finish saving (in the background), then you can finally add it to the relation and save the parent object.

Since there's no in-built promises support (there are some 3rd party ones you might want to look at), you'll have to use nesting.

Consider creating an array of `PFFile` objects and using `saveAllInBackground:block:`. In the block create the `homeImages` objects and put them in an array, calling save-all again. Lastly in that completion block add them all to the relation and call `saveInBackground` on your `homeObject`.